# Delete 3D matrix c++

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to delete a matrix created whit "new", but the compiler return the error message:
"CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

That's my code:

```
//alloc
rede->y = new float**[rede->p];
for (i=0; i < rede->p; i++) {
    rede->y[i] = new float*[rede->c];
    for (j=0; j < rede->c; j++) {
        rede->y[i][j] = new float [rede->n[i] + 1];
    }
}

//...

//d-lloc
for (i=0; i < rede->p; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < rede->c; j++) {
        delete (rede->y[i][j]); //here is the error. If I comment this line, the compiler do not accuse any error.
    }
    delete (rede->y[i]);
}
delete (rede->y);
```

Nothing goes wrong when I try that way:

```
rede->y = new float**[rede->p];
for (i=0; i < rede->p; i++) {
    rede->y[i] = new float*[rede->c];
    for (j=0; j < rede->c; j++) {
        rede->y[i][j] = new float [rede->n[i] + 1];
        delete (rede->y[i][j]);
    }
    delete (rede->y[i]);
}
delete (rede->y);
```

Whats wrong with the first code?
Thanks.

Comment: `delete (rede->y);`  Wrong form of `delete`.  You allocated an array, so you need `delete[]`.

Comment: Also, remove those `...` from your post and post a full program that does nothing *except* allocate and then deallocate.  If there is no issue, then the offending code is in those `...` you posted.

Comment: This version shows no errors:  http://ideone.com/YoXnsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't advocate using `float***` (triple-star programming), I will try and give you information on the code you posted.  Note that you would more than likely be better off using a container class, such as `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

The one error that I do see is you're not using the correct form of `delete`.  Since you allocated an array, you should be using `delete[]`.  Even though you're just allocating pointers or `float`, using the wrong form of `delete` is undefined behavior.

Second, we don't know what those values of `rede->p`, `rede->c`, or `rede->n` are, therefore we don't know if the problem is within these variables.

Third, your post is doing something with this allocated memory, but you didn't show us.  It may be the code you didn't show is causing memory corruption -- you should check for this.

So to show you an example, here is a program that compiles and deallocates properly.

```
int main()
{
    const int nPages = 5;
    const int nRows = 10;
    const int nCols = 20;
    float ***mat = new float**[nPages];
    for (int i = 0; i < nPages; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new float*[nRows];
        for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++)
            mat[i][j] = new float[nCols];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nPages; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++)
            delete [] mat[i][j]; 
        delete [] mat[i];
    }
    delete[] mat;
}
```

Note the correct usage of `delete[]`.

Given this, if the dimensions of the matrix are fixed, then the following version reduces the number of calls to `new[]`, thus making `delete[]` a little easier to handle:

```
int main()
{
    const int nPages = 5;
    const int nRows = 10;
    const int nCols = 20;
    float ***mat = new float**[nPages];
    for (int i = 0; i < nPages; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new float*[nRows];
        float *pool = new float[nRows * nCols];
        for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++, pool+=nCols)
            mat[i][j] = pool;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nPages; i++)
    {
        delete [] mat[i][0];
        delete [] mat[i];
    }
    delete[] mat;
}
```

In the first example, the calls to `new[]` totalled 56 calls.  The second example has only 11 calls to `new[]`.  Both examples accomplish the same thing, but using slightly different ways of allocating the memory.  The second version allocates all the data in one call to `new[]` instead of calling `new[]` for each row of data.

Also note that if the number of columns (the innermost dimension) is increased, the number of calls to `new[]` for the first example would increase dramatically due to the innermost loop having to call `new[]`, while the number of calls to `new[]` in the second case stays at 11, regardless if the innermost loop increases.

The calls to `delete[]` in the second example are also different in that we only need to delete `mat[i][0]` to delete an entire page of data, instead of having to loop to delete each row of data.